# Diretiva para detectar click fora de um elemento?

Tags: angularjs

No AngularJS, temos a diretive `ngClick`, que serve para executar uma ação quando um elemento é clicado.

Eu gostaria de criar uma diretiva, chamada `ngClickout` para que, quando o clique ocorrer fora do elemento, executar uma ação.

Como posso fazer isso? Eu não tenho muita "intimidade" ainda com o `angular.element` (e não quero usar jQuery).

Comment: Qual seria a finalidade desse evento? Podes dar algum exemplo prático? Queres, por exemplo, disparar o "clique" em um `input file` ao clicar em uma `div`?

Comment: @CelsomTrindade para algo parecido com o que eu fazia no jQuery. Eu costumava estender o jQuery e criar uma função chamada `clickOut`, para reutilizar em qualquer elemento que eu desejasse: quando clicar fora, executar uma ação.  Por exemplo, eu poderia mudar o valor de uma variável ao clicar fora desse "determinado elemento"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O método mais simples de se criar uma diretiva que obtenha o resultado que você procura, seria usar o `element.bind('click');` que irá detectar o clique no elemento.

Apenas um detalhe antes de demonstrar o código, é interessante que você não use o prefixo `ng`, por convenção, para evitar que venha a ter conflito com outras diretivas nativas do Angular. Por isso, recomendo que use seu próprio prefixo, como `wm`.

Então veja um exemplo básico de diretiva para detectar o clique:

```
.directive('wmClick', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            element.bind('click', function(e) {
                //Execute sua função aqui
            });
        }
    }
});

<button wm-click type="button">Clique aqui</button>
```

Com isso, ao clicar no botão, você irá chamar o evento da diretiva. Eu costumo usar isso quando possuo alguma função comum ao `app` todo, como por exemplo, o log out de um usuário. Então ao invés de declarar um `controller` global só para essa finalidade, eu crio uma diretiva.

Agora, caso você precise propagar alguma mudança de valores, como dito nos comentários, vai precisar usar o `$scope.$digest()` ou `$scope.$apply()`, dependendo se a mudança é dentro da mesma diretiva ou em escopo global. Veja o exemplo:

```
.directive('wmClick', function($scope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            element.bind('click', function(e) {
                //Execute sua função aqui

                $scope.meuNome = 'Novo Nome';
                $scope.$digest(); //Para aplicar a mudança dentro da própria diretiva
                $scope.$apply(); //Para aplicar a mudança fora da diretiva
            });
        }
    }
});
```

---

**Editado**: Respondendo a questão do comentário

No caso de você querer propagar um evento clicando no `body` para remover um elemento de sua tela, como um modal, por exemplo, eu recomendaria o uso de eventos aliado ao `$document` assim você pode inclusive detectar o uso da tecla `ESC`, veja o exemplo:

```
.directive('wmClick', function($document, $scope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            //Usado para clique diretamente no elemento
            element.bind('click', function(e) {
                //Execute sua função aqui

                $scope.meuNome = 'Novo Nome';
                $scope.$digest(); //Para aplicar a mudança dentro da própria diretiva
                $scope.$apply(); //Para aplicar a mudança fora da diretiva
            });

            //Usado para detectar clique no body ou tecla "ESC"
            var close = function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    scope.valor = false;
                });
            };

            $document.on('click', close); //Detecta um clic no documento e chama a função

            $document.on('keyup', function(e) { //Detecta o uso da tecla "ESC" e chama a função
                if (e.keyCode === 27) {
                    close();
                }
            });

            scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                $document.off('click', close);
                $document.off('keyup', close);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Entendi a ideia. Mas vamos supor que eu queria fazer um elemento "desaparecer" ao clicar no "body" ao invés de clicar no próprio elemento.   No angular tem algum jeito de detectar isso? Tipo isso [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/rv29hm0x/)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters atualizei minha resposta. Basicamente você precisa "ouvir" o evento do documento ao invés do elemento específico.